# C Rotating String Program?

Tags: c, arrays, string, character, caesar-cipher

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
int rotation, i=0;
char str[80]={0}; 
printf("Enter Text: ");
scanf("%[^\n]", str); 
printf("\"");

printf("Enter Rotation: ");
scanf("%i", &rotation);

while(str[i]) 
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        printf("%c\n", 'a' + (str[i] - 'a' + rotation)%26); 
        else    
        printf("%c\n", str[i]);
        i++;    
    }

return 0;
}
```

Have a hard time understanding this line of code (printf("%c\n", 'a' + (str[i] - 'a' + rotation)%26); )

Can anyone just write a brief explanation quickly it would help me

Comment: This is a simple cipher known as the [Caesar Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).  Reputedly, Julius used an offset of 3 (and the 23-letter [Latin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin#Phonology), rather than the more modern 26-letter variant — J, U, and W are the newcomers).

Comment: Be careful not to learn the wrong lesson with this tutorial: This algorithm only "encrypts" the lower case letters of the [Basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet) letters. Text—even English text—uses more letters than all of the Basic Latin letters. Arithmetic on character values has very limited applicability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is taking the user's input text and on a per character basis *rotating* it through the alphabet based on the number entered. It works because of the [ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

The line in question takes the character a user entered, offsets it by `'a'` (which equals 91 in ASCII), adds in the `rotation` factor then performs modulo `26` on the result (how many characters are there in the alphabet again?) to make sure the result is still a lowercase character.

I bet you could find a good way to break this program :)

Comment: One way to break this is `EBCDIC` instead of ASCII as letter characters are not required to be sequential according to the C standard [and they aren't in EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Compatibility_with_ASCII)